# Mechanism of hydroboration oxidation reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox

I know that the hydroboration reaction is used to add $\ce{H2O}$ to the double bond in an anti-Markovnikov fashion.

I went to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroboration%E2%80%93oxidation_reaction) and found the following mechanism:

[image: Hydroboration mechanism]

But I could not understand as to why the addition is *syn.*

Comment: In its current form, 's not clear to me why this got downvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The addition is concerted, i.e., everything happens at the same time; there aren't multiple steps to the addition. You can expect the boron to go on one face of the double bond while the hydrogen goes on the other face. There's just no way for the hydrogen to reach over to the other side for the *anti*-attack. It has to be *syn*.

Answer (score -1):

It develops a cyclic transition state between C double bond:

```
  CH3     H
    \    /
     C--C 
 H/       \H
  |         |
  |         |
  H---  ---BH2
```

Then replaces BH2 by OH

Comment: Please draw an image and upload that; it is impossible to understand what you wrote down there.

Comment: I did the best I could with it, but I would heed @Jan's sage advice here.