# A IChO-2014 problem involving reaction mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry

[image]

This is a problem of IChO-2014(&solution).But I am having trouble working out reaction mechanism of the second reaction or even how the product B formed. This reaction is somewhat new to me. And googling didn't help much.

Just need a little hint on this regard.

Comment: And Googling didn't seem much help.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69042 and http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62177

Comment: The key also for the second reaction is the use of a very bulky borane. There are two sites for hydroboration, and we are selecting for the one that is less hindered. Using a hindered borane at low temperature means that we can avoid reacting much at the tri-substituted double bond. Too bad it also takes seven days to react at the less substituted double bond.

Comment: @Zhe What does acetone do in forming B to C?

Comment: As usual, below the arrow, it's solvent.

Comment: @zhe why did the alcohol dirctly converted to acid? Is CrO3 too strong oxidezer?

Comment: Very conventional oxidation with acidic chromium trioxide. Too strong is relative. Here, the acid was the desired product, so it was strong enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A to B is a classic hydroboration of the least hindered double bond followed by oxidation of the trialkyl borane.